# What does the 3 above the staff represent?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, rhythm

From the below image, What does the 3 above the three quarter notes represent? I attempted to look it up [here](http://piano.about.com/library/Sheet-Music-Symbols/bl_Piano-Notation-Symbols.htm) but I did not find anything similar to it.

[image: staff]

I am assuming it makes the 3 notes shorter, due to the fact that if you add together the three ♪, the 8<sup>th</sup> rest, and the three ♩ you get a total of 1¼. But I would like a detailed explanation of what I should be doing when I play it.

Comment: Here is a related question about triplets for you: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/what-exactly-does-a-3-mean-over-a-quarter-note-and-an-8th-note

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 3 indicates a triplet. The quarter notes should be played at 2/3rds their normal duration. You end up with the three quarter notes taking up the last 2 beats of the measure, divided equally.

Comment: A tip that was useful to me as to how to play it when you don't know how a triplet over several beats sounds or feel : play 3 "eight" notes for both quarter note, making it 6 1/8 over 2 1/4. Then only play the 1st, 3rd and 5th notes of that group : that is where the attacks of the triplet will fall. A bit like adding fractions with different denominators, really.

Comment: @Pif, actually that is EXACTLY what I did last night trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: That's because it's the right way to do it (^_^).

As an example, here's someone taking this approach too far http://www.vai.com/tempo-mental/ (O_o)

Comment: The way I learned the timing was from "Carol of the Bells"; the rhythm is a transposition of a triplet pattern over a tuplet pattern. BTW, in triplet times like 6/8, you can see the reverse; a "2" and bracket will be placed over two notes, indicating a "tuplet"; those two notes should be played in the space of three of the same note value in the natural time.

Comment: As for quintuplets and septuplets, etc, they are seen, especially in solo pieces and etudes. In those situations, the advice I got from a working professional violinist was, don't try to count or subdivide it; just cram all the notes into the space you're given and chalk up any variance as artistic expression :)

Comment: I've heard words with equal syllable weight used as mnemonics for getting the spacing of quintuplets, etc. correct, such as "u-ni-ver-si-ty" to represent a quintuplet. Oddly, for triplets, I learned "tri-pl-et" with a syllabic L, instead of a proper three-syllable word.