# Half oval 3 over notes

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, classical-music

I'm a bit confused about this graphic, notice the half ovals on top with the 3 in the center:

[image]

Is that a "triplet" and the same as this graphic in guitar pro?

[image]

Please note that I have searched but I am asking because  one has a oval kind of thingy on top and the second has a bracket kind of thingy.
Some of the answers I found are:

[What exactly does a 3 mean over a quarter note and an 8th note?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/what-exactly-does-a-3-mean-over-a-quarter-note-and-an-8th-note)

I just want to double check instead of getting my ground/foundation wrong as I am very much still learning this stuff.

Are they the same and are they both triplets or something else?

Comment: It could be a combination of a triplet and a slur - a slurred triplet - although normally I would expect to see t he slur under the heads not over the beam. Also for beamed triplets the bracketing isn't needed since the beam performs the role of the bracketing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are both triplets.

If they were not eigth note triplets, the measure would not add up to 4 quarter notes, but instead 5 quarter notes. Another thing to note is notice how the notes are beamed to make 4 groups. This is  to clearly show each beat i.e. each quarter note. As you can see, those notes form  one group together equaling 1 quarter note so there's no doubt that they are triplets.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Is there any particular reason one is curved (half oval) and the other "brackety"? New style or just differences in the software or 'old' vs 'modern' way of writing it?

Comment: @Ryan I'm sure it's just the style of whatever software created it. The bracket is much, much more common, but they are equivalent.

Comment: It does not matter. Sometimes it is notated with just a number three above the triplets

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a note that the "graphic" does not really matter, if there is a 3 on top, its a triplet. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Cheers!

Comment: My impression is that the curved bracket was much more common in older music. I started music lessons a half-century ago, and the square bracket is actually less familiar to me.

Comment: Note the number 3 is printed with italics. That way it is different from fingering suggestions. Regarding square brackets: This way it is different from slurs.